# Two dataframes need to be compared and get answer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have two dataframe as follows,

questionMaster:

| Q_ID | Q_Text | Choice_ID | Choice_Text | Correct_Choice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | What is 2 multiply by 2? | 1 | three | 0 |
| 101 |  | 2 | Four | 1 |
| 101 |  | 3 | Six | 0 |
| 102 | ___the king of the jungle? | 1 | Tiger | 0 |
| 102 |  | 2 | Zebra | 0 |
| 102 |  | 3 | Lion | 1 |

answerReponse:

| Student_ID | Q_ID | Student_Choice_Response |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 101 | 2 |
| 2001 | 102 | 3 |
| 2002 | 101 | 1 |
| 2002 | 102 | 3 |
| 2003 | 101 | 3 |
| 2003 | 102 | 1 |

I want to compare the response given by students with the question master and want to predict whether students answered is Correct or not (i.e) 0 means wrong and 1 means correct. I would like to know how to create dataframe by comparing like this,

| Student_ID | Q_ID | Student_Choice_Response | IsCorrectorNot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 101 | 2 | 1 |
| 2001 | 102 | 3 | 1 |
| 2002 | 101 | 1 | 0 |
| 2002 | 102 | 3 | 1 |
| 2003 | 101 | 3 | 0 |
| 2003 | 102 | 1 | 0 |

I used the functional programming as follows

```
def isCorrect(x):
 if x['Q_ID']== 101 and x['Student_Choice_Response']==2:
  return 1
 elif x['Q_ID']== 102 and x['Student_Choice_Response']==3:
  return 1
 else:
  return 0

answerReponse['IsCorrectorNot']= answerReponse.apply(isCorrect,axis=1)
```

This code works fine. Is there an alternate solution to compare two dataframe and predict the answers?

Answer (score 0):

The compare method in pandas shows the differences between two of the Data Frames where it compares the  two data frames, row-wise and column-wise, and presents the differences with respect to the formation. The compare method can only compare Data Frames of the same shape or size of the data, with exact dimensions and identical row and column labels or you may use list's to differentiate the two data set's. I'm not good expert but this might work.